# get out of range element from vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am doing some tests and got around this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Person{
public:
    std::string name;

    Person(const char *name):
        name(name){
            printf("c-tor for %s\n", name);
        };

    void print(){
        printf(">> %s\n", name.c_str());
    };
};

int main(){
    std::vector<Person> v;

    v.push_back("Ivan");
    v.push_back("Stoyan");
    v.push_back("Dragan");

    v[10].print();
}
```

If I do it with `std::cout`, it crashes. However if I do it with `printf`, it prints:

> c-tor for Ivan
>  c-tor for Stoyan
>  c-tor for Dragan
>   >> (null)

Is this working "correctly" just by chance and coincidence?

> Portable programs should never call this function with an argument n
>   that is out of range, since this causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.  So asking for seemingly working stuff is useless.

Comment: It's just undefined. Behavior depends on compiler you use.

Comment: It is not working "correctly". Since it is undefined behaviour (as you quoted yourself), there is no "correct" way.

Comment: Undefined behavior means anything can happen. It can even work as expected, which (ironically) can sometimes be very frustrating: you may first think it works and much later your program crashes or behaves very strange, and you don't find the source of the problem... To put it in a nutshell, avoid undefined behavior by all means, even if it seems to work at first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this working "correctly" just by chance and coincidence?

Yes.

You have given the reason yourself with the quote

> Portable programs should never call this function with an argument n
>   that is out of range, since this causes **undefined behavior**.

Accessing `v[10]` when `v.size()` is less than `11` is undefined behavior and thus your program may crash or give unexpected (sometimes seeming correct) output.

`cout` may print `std::string` in a different way than accessing `std::string::c_str` and thus `cout` and `printf` may give different results.